# load one thing from service only once on any page

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have a call to `/accounts` that I only want to happen once, immediately, on whatever page a user lands on. Once that call is made, it will either kick the user back to a home page or will add that info to the store. If it is in the store, I don't want it to be called again.

Currently I'm trying to do something like this using `take(1)`:

```
@Effect()
loadAccounts$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(actions.ActionTypes.LoadAccounts),
    switchMap((action: actions.LoadAccounts) => {
        return this.accountService.getAccounts().pipe(
            map(accts => new actions.LoadAccountsSuccess(accts)),
            catchError(error => {
                this.store.dispatch(new LoadAccountsFailure(error));
                return EMPTY;
            }),
        );
    }),
    take(1),
);
```

A problem I'm seeing is that with:

```
export const selectWorkspacesLoadInProgress = AppSelectors.selectChangesIndicatorInProgress([
    AccountActions.ActionTypes.LoadAccounts,
    ConfigActions.ActionTypes.LoadProjects,
    WorkspaceListActions.ActionTypes.LoadWorkspaces,
]);
```

After we get the account info loaded into the store, I'm seeing the loadInProgress get stuck on any call to loadAccounts after. The action for load account has `@ShowInProgressIndicator(ActionTypes.LoadAccounts)` and load account success/failure then have `@HideIndicator(ActionTypes.LoadAccounts)` ... but with `take(1)`, it seems we still trigger the `show` but the `hide`s never get triggered.

I'm also a bit unsure how I should handle this from multiple pages... now, on the main page component for any page I'm using something like this within `ngOnInit`:

```
    this.store.dispatch(new AccountActions.LoadAccounts());
```

I have one component that needs to make an additional call after the accounts call is successful. I am doing that with this effect:

```
@Effect()
addServiceToWorkspace$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(actions.ActionTypes.AddService),
    mergeMap((action: actions.AddService) =>
        this.serviceService.add(action.request).pipe(
            mergeMap(() => [new actions.AddServiceSuccess(action.request.workspaceId), new actions.StopAddingService()]),
            catchError((error) => of(new actions.AddServiceFailure(errorToErrorMessage(error)))),
        ),
    ),
);
```

but I've noticed that this gets called on any page that I am in, and I'm not sure how to limit it... other than possibly creating almost duplicate `loadAccounts` action/effects for every page.

---

**Trying to summarize...**

What is a good way to accomplish having 1 service call get made for an item in a store per session regardless of which component they land on... and have those components depend on (wait for) this data to be there (either call from the service to get the data, or use data from store) ... without messing up things that depend on the `success` or `failure` actions to have been reached?

Comment: Look at the RxJS#shareReplay operator. Everything before `shareReplay(1)` will get run only once, after that the value is cashed and returned.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add an `if` to your selector pipeline. Something like this:

```
this.products$ = this.store.select(getProducts).pipe(
  tap(x => {
    if (x.length === 0) {
      this.store.dispatch(ProductActions.loadProducts());
    }
  })
);
```

Not sure if this technique would be "best practices" though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using NgRx, you could create a field in the store to hold that account-information and all components requiring the account-information can simply select it from the store.

That covers the select part, now for loading something only once immediately when the application is launched there is a built in functionality: take a look at Angular's APP_INITIALIZER. In your core.module.ts (or app.module.ts if you don't have that) you can use it like so:

```
providers: [
   {provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: callAccountPage, multi: true, deps: [AccountService]}
]
```

The factory is just creating a function that will call your Service, e.g.:

```
function checkForExistingSession(accountService: AccountService): Function {
  console.log("initializing app - calling accountPage);
  return () => {
    return accountService.loadAccount();
  };
}
```

Now your loadAccount() function is nothing special - it will do the http-call and then emit an Action for NgRx to store the account-information in your store.

The last part is how to ensure that components wait for the actual data to arrive. There is multiple ways. For example you can just use a pipe with filter when selecting the data from the store. I personally use a Guard for this exact case - since my User-Information is required by most components, the Guard ensures that a route can only be activated after the User-Information has arrived (and the user is allowed to do so)